# Drupal7+Omega Theme: How to narrow the 20px gutter between columns in 960 grid?

Tags: theming

Is it possible to alter the allmighty 20px gutter in 960px grid especially when using with Drupal 7 Omega subtheme?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you search Google for "Drupal Omega custom grid", you find links like:

- [Creating and Setting up a Custom Grid for Omega 3.x](http://groups.drupal.org/node/164684)
- [How to define my own 960 grid ?](http://drupal.org/node/1321098)

Hope that helps.